# CREATE AS using SELECT TOP 10000

Tags: oracle

I need to create a table from another table but I only want the last 10000 records to be added in the new table. Can any one tell me how this can be done by modifying this statement:

```
create table export_cluster_125m
as
(select * from cluster_125m);
```

Comment: oracle uses rownum, so you'd want a clause like `WHERE ROWNUM < 10000`

Comment: oracle don't store order of rows in table. You can not select the last 10000 rows, if you do not store the order they are added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you want the "last" 10000 rows.  Assuming this can be determined by a column such as `created_date` you would need to order by that column (descending) and then take the first 10000 rows returned by that query.  This can be done using ROWNUM, but **not** like this:

```
-- Will not work correctly
select * from cluster_125m
where rownum <= 10000
order by created_date desc;
```

That will return some 10000 rows, ordered by created_date (descending) - but they will not generally be the latest 10000 rows.  To do that you need to nest the query like this:

```
select * from
( select * from cluster_125m
  order by created_date desc
)
where rownum <= 10000;
```

Now all rows are sorted in descending order, and **then** the first 10000 are taken.

Comment: I have just done it on one table and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the answer and also for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
create table export_cluster_125m
as
select * from cluster_125m where rownum<=10000;
```

Comment: That will give you 10000 random rows.